# PostAsXmlAsync Serialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-mvc

I have an API call that correctly responds to a XML Post and deserializes the object properly as a parameter. However, when trying to Post programmatically, I keep getting null as the parameter in my API function.

```
client.Timeout = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:59118/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

...

XmlReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
Record postValRec = null;
while (rdr.Read())
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Record));
    postValRec = (Record)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
}
rdr.Close();
conn.Close();                

try
{
    response = await client.PostAsXmlAsync("api/Submission", postValRec);
    string html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(html);
}
```

I have verified that `postValRec` is the proper object, so it is not a problem with that.

When executing `client.PostAsXmlAsync` the API function gets 'null' for the parameter. Posting the object manually through Postman as XML works fine, however, so I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: Have you traced a successful request through [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and compared it to.a failed request? Might point you in the right direction. If not, post the two requests here (from the requests' raw inspector) and maybe we can help further!

Comment: Take a look at this article... It seems we need to use an XmlMediaTypeFormatter     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493266/httpclient-does-not-serialize-correctly