# HttpClient does not serialize XML correctly

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

When calling HttpClient's extension method `PostAsXmlAsync`, it ignores the `XmlRootAttribute` on the class.  Is this behaviour a bug?

**Test**

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("record")]
class Account 
{
    [XmlElement("account-id")]
    public int ID { get; set }
}


var client = new HttpClient();
await client.PostAsXmlAsync(url, new Account())
```

Comment: did you post the same question again.. from Aug 11th 2014 or similar ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251240/invalidoperationexception-on-a-postasxmlasync-call

Comment: do you also know what the url is at the time of calling client.PostAsXMLAsync..? if so just replace url with the actual http url and try it that way..

Comment: Different question - I'm using Attribute based serialization now. And I get the same error when using the right url

Comment: Can you add the XML generated by `PostAsXmlAsync`?

Comment: looks like your are missing something try this link as well it seems to be more in line with what I think you are trying to do.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am wondering if something like this would not work for you using `XMLTypeAttribute`
`[XmlType(TypeName = "record")]
    [Serializable]
    public class Account
    {
  [XmlElement("account-id")]
  public int ID { get; set }
    }`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looking at the [source code of `PostAsXmlAsync`](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/27743439/#l-123), we can see that it uses `XmlMediaTypeFormatter` which internally uses `DataContractSerializer` and **not** `XmlSerializer`. The former doesn't respect the `XmlRootAttribute`:

```
public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsXmlAsync<T>(this HttpClient client, Uri requestUri, T value, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
      return client.PostAsync(requestUri, value, new XmlMediaTypeFormatter(),
                    cancellationToken);
}
```

In order to achieve what you need, you can create a your own custom extension method which explicitly specifies to use `XmlSerializer`:

```
public static class HttpExtensions
{
    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsXmlWithSerializerAsync<T>(this HttpClient client, Uri requestUri, T value, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return client.PostAsync(requestUri, value,
                      new XmlMediaTypeFormatter { UseXmlSerializer = true },
                      cancellationToken);
    }
}
```