# ASP.NET Web API returns NULL for object when using XML

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I've tried to follow the instructions I found, but still it does not work.

I have following class

```
public class TodoItem
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
    public TodoItem() { }
}
```

My server has following POST Method

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]TodoItem item)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            TodoRepository.Current.Add(item);
            return Ok(item);
        }
        return BadRequest("Object is null");
    }
```

In my WebApiConfig.cs I have added following line

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

On the client side I am using HttpClient as follows:

```
var postTask = client.PostAsXmlAsync<TodoItem>("", item);
```

My Post method on server receives null for the item object.

Comment: I can not see url in your call. e.g 

`var respone = await httpClient.PostAsXmlAsync(requestUri, Item);`

How your method gets called?

Comment: The URL is set as follows `client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5342/api/todos/");` It works perfect when I use `postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<TodoItem>("", item);`

Comment: Could you please try the answer mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25494252/309395)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, solved the problem with the help of Nilesh Thakkar

I have added following extension method

```
public static class HttpExtensions
{
    public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsXmlWithSerializerAsync<T>(this HttpClient client, string requestUri, T value)
    {
        return client.PostAsync(requestUri, value,
                      new XmlMediaTypeFormatter { UseXmlSerializer = true });   
    }
}
```

The call from HttpClient now looks

```
var postTask = client.PostAsXmlWithSerializerAsync<TodoItem>("", item);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816478/wcf-datacontract-datamember-order) answer could be also useful. PostAsXmlAsync uses XmlMediaTypeFormatter which internally uses DataContractSerializer, which creates XML from DataContract in alphabetical order(XmlSerializer - in defined order).
So, using "Order Parameter" in the DataMemberAttribute class could help with PostAsXmlAsync-deserialization-issue:

`[DataMember(Order = index)]`